# Case in-sensitive fish completion search

Tags: fish

Is it possible to set the fish's shell completion search to ignore case sensitivity? It would be very convenient for me to have this behavior especially when comes to Git branches.

Tried to Google but I did not manage to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

File & directory tab completion uses fuzzy matching, which includes case insensitive matching, by default.

Comment: Hmmm are you sure? Does it needs to be configured somewhere? Originally the problem for me was mainly in the Git branches completion, since on FS I am using only lowercase names, but I tried it also for file completation and still nothing... 
I thought that maybe it is because of my fish version (I had version 2.2), so I upgraded to last realease (2.7.1) and the problem still is present.
Here is example:
http://i65.tinypic.com/2a6ttg7.png

Comment: You're triggering the pager search, presumably because one tab isn't enough. The fuzzy searching needs to match at least part of the file name - there's no lowercase h at all, but if you use either `ah` or `H` then you should get a match.